# iPhone - UIWebView: Detect User Scrolling to Bottom of Page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

So, I have a UIView with a UIWebView inside serving up a local HTML file (a document preview).  I also have "Accept" & "Reject" UIButtons.  I need these buttons to only appear after the user has scrolled to the bottom of the web page.  Is there a way to capture an event for scrolling to the bottom of a UIWebView?

I have not seen any good answers for this, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

UIWebView conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate.  As such, you can create a subclass of UIWebView (say, ScrollDetectWebView) and capture the calls to the UIScrollViewDelegate.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [super scrollViewDidScroll: scrollView];

    // Whatever scroll detection you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

huh?

Why not just included the buttons on the bottom of the page?

Comment: The buttons are not in the HTML, they are in the UIView that also has the UIWebView.

Comment: Ah, in that case. You can present the HTML in a separate viewController as modal view with the HTML and the buttons on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript lets handle the scrolling event and send message to Objective-c.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    CGSize fittingSize = [self.webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

    CGFloat height1 = scrollView.bounds.origin.y + self.webView.bounds.size.height;

    CGFloat height2 = fittingSize.height;

    int delta = fabs(height1 - height2);

    if (delta < 30) {

       NSLog(@"HELLO!!! You reached the page end!");
    }
    }
```